# RewriteRule Remove the query string

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

In the `.htaccess`, I need to remove the query string

```
?lang=ca, from ca/blog/?lang=ca
```

Said in another way, I want to redirect from:

```
www.example.com/ca/blog/?lang=ca
```

to

```
www.example.com/ca/blog/
```

These are two of the different things I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^ca/blog/ /ca/blog/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ca/blog/$ /ca/blog/ [QSD]
```

What is wrong with my options and how to do it right?

(`ca/blog/?lang=ca` does not exist. This is why now I need to redirect to `ca/blog/`. If I do not redirect Google, considers that these are two different pages)

The documentation explain how to remove the query string:

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

But I do not know how to apply to my case or what I tried does not work

My second solution uses the flag [QSD] Query String Discard. Probably there is something I do not understand, because it does not work either

Comment: Post the whole url please

Comment: @sjsam: I updated the question with the whole url

Comment: The questios is not clear, You wish the users to see `www.myDomain.com/ca/blog/` right?

Comment: Usually things happen the other way, you provide the users with a neat url which they can remember and make the server fetch the complex one with more information.

Comment: This is to solve a problem in Google Search Console www.example.com/ca/blog/?lang=ca does not exist anymore so I want to redirect to the new www.example.com/ca/blog/ the good address

Comment: Do you already have a .htaccess in `ca/blog/` sub-directory OR `ca/blog` is not a real folder?

Comment: I have a .htaccess in the root of the site. ca/blog/ are real folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(ca/blog/?)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Your solution is very complicated. See the documentation: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: Yes I have read those documents many times. Just removal of query string is fairly simple and you can do that with just one rule: `RewriteRule ^ca/blog/?$ $0? [L,R]` but then it will remove any query string not just `lang=` and `?lang=` will not be available internally as well.

Comment: Why this does not work? RewriteRule ^ca/blog/?lang=ca /ca/blog/? [L,R=301]

Comment: Because **you cannot match query string in `RewriteRule`** directive

Comment: Your option works. You put %{REQUEST_URI}? Is there any special reason? why not simply: /ca/blog/?

Comment: So that we can avoid repeating same `ca/blog/` in source and target. In future if you have to change this, just change at one place.

Answer (score 0):

At the very beginning check if

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

is uncommented in the `httpd.conf` file.  When apache is running check :

```
httpd -M | grep rewrite
```

to verify that `mod_rewrite` is indeed enabled. Once these conditions are actually met below stuff works.

**Broken URL :**

```
http://www.example.com/ca/blog/?lang=ca
```

**Rule**

```
RewriteEngine    On
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^lang=ca$
RewriteRule (.*)/  $1/? [R=permanent]
```

**Server will fetch this**

```
http://www.example.com/ca/blog/
```

**Explanation**

1. In the `RewriteCond` we check if the query string `lang` is `ca`.
2. If the condition is satisfied we append an empty query string `?` at the end. And since your original url is broken we put `R=permanent` to tell the server that the redirect is permanent.

Comment: The question is remove the querry string

Comment: Remember, I ask to go from ca/blog/?lang=ca to ca/blog/

Comment: @segon : I have updated the answer to fit your requirement. Please lemme know this works

Comment: @segon . I have confirmed it will work with [htaccess test](http://postimg.org/image/so2y9btyp/). Moreover i have not used options like `QSD` (which causes the query the query to be discarded) compatibility reasons. If my solution doesn't work for you probably have other agencies in action for the same url.

Answer (score 0):

The query string is not part of what you are matching in a rewrite rule. If you want to match anything in the query string, you need a RewriteCond directive, limiting the next RewriteRule to the condition you specify.

For example:

```
RewriteCond lang=cr %{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^/foo /foo [R=301]
```

This will redirect `/foo?lang=cr` to `/foo`, but `/foo?lang=en` and `/foo` will remain unaffected.

Of course the pattern might need to be a bit stricter, because it will also match `/foo?langlang=crown` but nonetheless...

By the way, it might be easier to implement this in your application logic rather than in an .htaccess ....

Comment: I do not understand your answer. The title of my question is remove the de querry string. How your answer solve that?

Comment: If you wish to match on something in the querystring (which you do, specifically whether a lang is specified), you need to add a RewriteCond doing that match, you won't be able to solve it with just RewriteRules.

Comment: Do your answer remove the querry string?

Comment: Well, my answer is a bit more general than the exact problem you describe, but yes, it will remove the query string, because if you do want the querystring, you need to pass the QSA (query-string append) option to the rewrite rule. But I'll modify my answer a bit so it becomes clearer